# IE8 is adding a trailing slash to an HTML5 <main> tag

Tags: html, internet-explorer, drupal, respond.js

My site is a Drupal 7 installation. Basically the `<main>` tag is at some point become `<main/>`, and this breaks the site's layout in those browsers. Everything is up to date. I am using a SquareGrid-based theme.

This problem used to affect even more HTML5 elements in IE8 and lower, but then I installed the Respond.js module, which fixed the majority.

You can see the problem in IE8 at http://www.shototechnologies.com/content/shotolab-channel-setup-page

Thank you very much!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That's because IE8 doesn't support HTML5 elements. And because it doesn't understand the `<main>` element as a valid HTML element, it auto closes it.

You will either need to use an [HTML5 shim](https://code.google.com/p/html5shim/) for IE<9 or wrap the tag in a div with `class="main"` as a [fallback](http://decadecity.net/blog/2012/09/06/html5-elements-legacy-browsers).