# CSS seems to not being applied in IE8

Tags: css

I am working on a website which works fine in all browsers but when I try it in IE8 it seems like CSS is not being applied: http://www.greenbelieve.pt/pt/inicio

Does anyone has any idea what am I missing?

**UPDATE**

I added the following:

Replace this in your page

```
<!--[if IE]>
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
<![endif]-->

<!-- HTML5 shim and Respond.js IE8 support of HTML5 elements and media queries -->
<!--[if lt IE 9]>
  <script src="js/html5shiv-printshiv.min.js"></script>
  <script src="js/respond.min.js"></script>
<![endif]-->
```

But know the text seems to be huge ...

Comment: Oops... I didn't mean to close; reopening now. But the reason still applies: Please try to post some code here.

Comment: What css is not applied? Be more specific and post some code

Comment: How does a question like this get posted here from a user with 1500 rep?  At 1500 rep you'd think you'd know how to post here at this point.

Comment: And the CSS on your website is minified.. that's too difficult!

Comment: Also, does your CSS has support for IE8? If you only developed for modern browsers, you'll likely see weird stuff using IE8.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Replace this in your page `<head>`

```
<!--[if IE]>
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge,chrome=1" />
<![endif]-->
```

With this:

```
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">

<!-- HTML5 shim and Respond.js IE8 support of HTML5 elements and media queries -->
<!--[if lt IE 9]>
  <script src="js/html5shiv-printshiv.min.js"></script>
  <script src="js/respond.min.js"></script>
<![endif]-->
```

After you import **html5shiv** and **Respond.js** files to your project of course.

Comment: I changed the Edge code and it kind of solved it ... The other code I had but was in footer. The problem now is that the text is huge ... Any idea why?

Answer (score 0):

The first thing I noticed about your site is that the markup is wrapped in a `<main>` tag, which IE8 doesn't support - as others have said, **html5shiv** can help with this.

See also these questions:

[IE8 is adding a trailing slash to an HTML5 <main> tag](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16328779/ie8-is-adding-a-trailing-slash-to-an-html5-main-tag)

[HTML5 tags in IE 8 & IE 7](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19680929/html-5-tags-in-ie-8-and-ie-7)